# Epheremal upload on MongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I’m trying to build a little social media using mongoose, react, Multer principally, but I got a small problem: I don’t know how to make ephemeral posts on MongoDB…
Do you have any idea how to deal with this problem ?

Comment: If by "ephemeral posts"  you mean posts that get deleted after some time: take a look at [`expires`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schemadateoptions_SchemaDateOptions-expires).

Comment: Yeah, I think what you found is exactly what I need. Thanks 